# VBA Regex issue

Tags: regex, excel, vba

has VBA any good mechanism for checking, if the content of a given Excel Cell matches a specific regex?

In my case i want to know, if some cell has the format

```
m
m2
m1234
```

In fact, there's just one defined letter at the beginning, followed by a not specified amount of numbers.

How do I put this into an If-Else construct?

```
If Doc.Cells(1,1).Value ..... ???
```

greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get at the VBScript RegExp objects via Tools->References & adding "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

Alternatively a quick way to do it, if you don't need to check for a subsequent letter as in `m1234X1 is:

`if  Doc.Cells(1,1).Value like "[a-zA-Z]#*" then ...`

(This doesn't require a reference to anything)

Comment: I didn't VB could do RegEx.  That's great to know.

Comment: just another question...how do i check, if my string matches a regex like "abc_123" or "abc123" (where "abc" is always at the beginning?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VBA, but the regex `[a-zA-Z][0-9]*` might be able to match what you want.

Comment: in a strange way not... [mM][0-9]* only gives     m12, m1, m10

Answer (score 0):

Here is my RegexContains function. Pass it the cell and the pattern and it will return TRUE or FALSE if it contains it or not.

```
Function RegexContains(ByVal find_in As String, _
                       ByVal find_what As String, _
                       Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = find_what
RE.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
RE.Global = True
RegexContains = RE.Test(find_in)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Now, I'm not sure exactly what you want to find in your example, but if you want to know if the cell contains a single letter followed by one or more letters, then you would use (assuming the cell is A1):   =RegexContains(A1, "^\w\d+")

- The ^ marks the start of the sentence
- The \w marks a single alphabetic
  character (a-zA-Z)
- The \d+ marks one or more numeric
  characters[0-9]

I hope this helps.